# link qt5 libraries automatically pass extra fPIC flag to nvcc compiler by cmake cause error

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, cuda

I have a project based on cuda10.1, qt5. And I use cmake to manage the compilation. However the same cmake script work fine in Windows, but in Linux, I got error "Unknown option 'fPIC'" when compiling .cu files. I look into makefile, then find there is a extra error flag "-fPIC" passed to nvcc compiler. Spending hours of testing, I find linking qt5 libraries will automatically pass extra fPIC flag which causes this error. I don't know this is bug or feature of cmake?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)   
project(PyPhysLeo LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)    

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets)        
if(Qt5_FOUND)
    message("Find QT5")
    link_libraries(Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui)     
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14 CACHE STRING "CXX STANDARD VERSION 11,14,17")          
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)        
set(CMAKE_CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON CACHE BOOL "DEFAULT SET SEPERABLE COMPILATION MODE") 
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -arch=sm_60") 

include_directories(${CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE})   

add_executable(test test.cu)
```

if you try above cmake script with any sample cuda code, you will get "nvcc fatal" error because it doesn't recognize fPIC flag.

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16915

Answer (score 3):

It is a problem with `qt5.cmake`. Thanks to Robert Crovella for commenting (see above) about the related information [gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16915](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16915). There is no perfect solution so far. But...

1. One solution, if you can separate your project into a library and an executable sub-projects, then you can cleanly avoid the issue altogether. Try to put all the .cu files in a library sub-project and only link qt5 in an executable sub-project. This is one way to avoid this problem.
2. Otherwise, you can try to modify the variable defined by `qt5.cmake`, for that solution please refer to [cmake issue 16915](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16915).

Comment: I came to the same conclusion: break down my project in two separate parts, one with Qt and one without.